# oracle regexp_like: using Perl regexp for AND operator equivalent

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-lookarounds, regexp-like

Is there an equivalent of the AND operator when writing a regular expression within Oracle REGEX_LIKE? I’ve been trying to select all cases where all three words must be contained within a string.  In the example below, I want to match all instances where **all three words**, **small** & **leather** & **goods** must be included in the string.  I’ve tried many online regex testers, and the regex syntax does precisely what I need it to do, but when I try and use the syntax within a REGEXP_LIKE expression, I get back zero matches

```
regexp_like(GLOBAL_CATEGORY,'(?=.*small)(?=.*leather)(?=.*goods)^.*$','i')
```

**regex tester example that accomplishes what I'm looking for:** [regexr.com/4vc1s](https://regexr.com/4vc1s)

```
Men/Outerwear/Leather/Sale **(NO MATCH)**
Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Small Leather Goods **(YES MATCH)**
Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Bags **(NO MATCH)**
Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Small Leather Goods **(YES MATCH)**
Men/Outerwear/Leather/Sale **(NO MATCH)**
Men/Small_Leather_Goods/Sale **(YES MATCH)**
Men/Outerwear/Leather **(NO MATCH)**
Men/Small_Leather_Goods **(YES MATCH)**
men>accessories>small>leather>goods **(YES MATCH)**
```

Comment: All of your examples have the words present in the order you listed them. The pattern would match, say, the 2nd example if the final part was just 'Small'. Can you confirm that you are trying to find them in any order within the string?

Comment: Yes, in  the order listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the words small, leather and goods in that order, please try :

`regexp_like(GLOBAL_CATEGORY,'*small.*.leather.*goods*', 'i')`

. *matches any character*
* *matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding subexpression*
i *is a match pattern which specifies case-insensitive matching*

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27c39d/1) here

Comment: The above works.  Since I know now that regexp_like does not follow the exact same syntax as Perl, if I would want to write for  AND NOT-  using the words above I want to match 'small and 'goods' but NOT 'leather. a and b but not c

Answer (score 4):

If you don't insist on regular expressions, then simple instr does the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as (
  2  select 'Men/Outerwear/Leather/Sale **(NO MATCH)**'                                      from dual union all
  3  select 'Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Small Leather Goods **(YES MATCH)**' from dual union all
  4  select 'Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Bags **(NO MATCH)**'                 from dual union all
  5  select 'Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Small Leather Goods **(YES MATCH)**' from dual union all
  6  select 'Men/Outerwear/Leather/Sale **(NO MATCH)**'                                      from dual union all
  7  select 'Men/Small_Leather_Goods/Sale **(YES MATCH)**'                                   from dual union all
  8  select 'Men/Outerwear/Leather **(NO MATCH)**'                                           from dual union all
  9  select 'Men/Small_Leather_Goods **(YES MATCH)**'                                        from dual union all
 10  select 'men>accessories>small>leather>goods **(YES MATCH)**'                            from dual
 11  )
 12  select * from test
 13  where instr(lower(col), 'small')   > 0
 14    and instr(lower(col), 'leather') > 0
 15    and instr(lower(col), 'goods')   > 0;

COL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Small Leather Goods **(YES MATCH)**
Men > Accessories > Bags & Leather Goods > Small Leather Goods **(YES MATCH)**
Men/Small_Leather_Goods/Sale **(YES MATCH)**
Men/Small_Leather_Goods **(YES MATCH)**
men>accessories>small>leather>goods **(YES MATCH)**

SQL>
```

(yes, I know, `(YES/NO MATCH)` isn't part of the string, but I was lazy to remove it.)

Comment: I think that this is what comes closest to the positive lookahead  regexp exhibited by OP (given that Oracle does not support lookahead assertions).